# Unable to add JavaScript on a page

Tags: javascript

I am using this, but I don't understand why it's not working.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/node/1') { 
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'sanskrit').'/sites/all/themes/sanskrit/scripts/jquery-1.4.3.min.js', 'inline'); 
  drupal_add_js('/sites/all/themes/sanskrit/scripts/scripts/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js');   
}
```

What I want to do is adding specific JavaScript files when the user is viewing the front page.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This should do it:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if (drupal_is_front_page()) {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') . '/MYSCRIPTS/myscript.js');
    $vars['scripts'] = drupal_get_js();
  }
}
```

FYI:  You'd use `drupal_get_js` in case any modules are also using `hook_preprocess_page` and setting new scripts themselves.

Also, I wouldn't just add a newer version of jQuery in willy nilly.  Try either [jQuery Update](http://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) or [jQuery Multi](http://drupal.org/project/jqmulti)

Comment: hey i am getting error in this line function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
what should i do

Comment: Are you getting `Undefined function` error? I guess it should be `drupal_is_front_page()` like my answer below.

Comment: Whoops...I've edited my answer.  That's one of those functions I ALWAYS type wrong.  Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 4):

Alternately: The [JavaScript Libraries](http://drupal.org/project/javascript_libraries) module. It doesn't let you limit the script to the front page, but is certainly much easier than writing a module just to load a script.

Answer (score 3):

If you are working with a module, you put it in hook_init like this:

```
function mymodule_init() {
  if(drupal_is_front_page()) {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'sanskrit') . '/sites/all/themes/sanskrit/scripts/jquery-1.4.3.min.js'); 
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'sanskrit') . '/sites/all/themes/sanskrit/scripts/scripts/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js');
  }
}
```

If you want to put it in preprocess_page:

```
function yourTheme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if(drupal_is_front_page()) {
     drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'sanskrit') . '/sites/all/themes/sanskrit/scripts/jquery-1.4.3.min.js'); 
     drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'sanskrit') . '/sites/all/themes/sanskrit/scripts/scripts/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js');
     $vars['scripts'] = drupal_get_js();
  }
}
```

Or you can put it in your theme.info file if you are building your own theme.

```
scripts[] = scripts/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js
```

Answer (score 2):

The best and simplest means to accomplish adding javascript to a front page is via [context](http://drupal.org/project/context) and [context add assets](http://drupal.org/project/context_addassets). Context and context add assets are exportable as well and you can create a feature to be used later on.

More about [context add assets](http://drupal.org/project/context_addassets):

> This module will add a reaction within context to add theme, module,
>   or custom folder files to your page(s).
>
> Ever wanted to quickly add a css file to a theme? Include a js file on
>   only one page (or section?)
>
> Make using multiple CSS files a breeze with this module and harness
>   the power of Context in your theme!

Answer (score 1):

It is not working because you are concatenating the string returned from `drupal_get_path('theme', 'sanskrit')` with `'/sites/all/themes/sanskrit/scripts/jquery-1.4.3.min.js'`; supposing that you didn't install Drupal in a sub-directory of the server root directory, the filename you are passing to `drupal_add_js()` is sites/all/themes/sanskrit/bbbsites/all/themes/sanskrit/scripts/jquery-1.4.3.min.js.

The code you should use is the following one.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/node/1') {
  $theme_path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'sanskrit'); 
  drupal_add_js($theme_path . '/scripts/jquery-1.4.3.min.js', 'inline'); 
  drupal_add_js($theme_path . '/scripts/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js');   
}
```

As others pointed out, to check if the user is viewing the front page, you just call [drupal_is_front_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_is_front_page/7).

Paths like sites/all/themes should be never hard coded in a theme/module code, as a theme could be installed in `sites/<domain.name>/themes/<theme.name>`, and a module could be installed in `sites/<domain.name>/modules/<module.name>`. Suppose that the Drupal installation is used for the domain blog.example.com, the Views module could be installed in sites/blog.example.com/modules/views, and a theme like the Whitebull theme could be installed in sites/blog.example.com/themes/whitebull.